# Restrict acces to ASP CORE web application

Tags: c#, security, asp.net-core, web-applications

I am building an ASP CORE 3.1 Web Application for a client, and he wants that the application will be accessible just from a specific machine (two ipads, two laptops, two phones).
Is that possible ?

I think of a Mac adress verification with a database but I want a secure solution if there is one.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You have to enable [CORS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-3.1#enable-cors).

There are three ways to enable CORS:

1. In middleware using a named policy or default policy.
2. Using endpoint routing.
3. With the `[EnableCors]` attribute.